# GCP Bigquery - query empty values from a record type value

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query all resources that has empty records on a specific column but I'm unable to make it work. Here's the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT
  service.description,
  project.labels,
  cost AS cost
FROM
  `xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx`
WHERE
  service.description = 'BigQuery' ;
```

Here's the results:

[image: results]

As you can see, I'm getting everything with that query, but as mentioned, I'm looking to get resources with empty records only for example record 229,230 so on.

Worth to mention that schema for the column I'm trying to query is:

```
project.labels  RECORD  REPEATED
```

The above was mentioned because I tried using several combinations of `WHERE` but everything ends up in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify empty repeated record - you can use `ARRAY_LENGTH` in `WHERE` clause like in below example

```
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(project.labels) = 0
```

Comment: glad it helped - consider also voting up the answer :o)

Comment: done ;) also do you recommend a book or place to learn better bigquery?

Comment: sure. go to https://www.google.com/search?q=bigquery+books and you can see the most recent (2019) book by famous Jordan T and Lak. You can also check very first one (2014) by same Jordan T. But to me the best place to learn better is product documentation :o)